# How to preserve the original string format with jinja template

Tags: python, html, jinja2

looking for a tip.

I have a random string generated elsewhere in format:

```
string = """[TAG1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                   Maecenas commodo diam ac sollicitudin vestibulum. Nunc ac
                   dignissim elit.
            [TAG2] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Maecenas commodo diam ac sollicitudin vestibulum. Nunc ac
            dignissim elit.
         """
```

Now I want to pass it to html template and preserve it's actual format.

Right now I am splitting the string by '\n' and:

```
 {% for line in comments %}
    <div>{{ line|safe}}</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

which results in:

```
string = """[TAG1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Maecenas commodo diam ac sollicitudin vestibulum. Nunc ac
            dignissim elit.
            [TAG2] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Maecenas commodo diam ac sollicitudin vestibulum. Nunc ac
            dignissim elit.
         """
```

Should I replace the spaces with html entity? What is the acceptable way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both seems good.. hope this helps

```
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{ string }}</p>
```

OR

```
<p style="white-space: pre-line;">{{ string }}</p>
```

Update

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    string = """[TAG1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                   Maecenas commodo diam ac sollicitudin vestibulum. Nunc ac
                   dignissim elit.
            [TAG2] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Maecenas commodo diam ac sollicitudin vestibulum. Nunc ac
            dignissim elit.
         """

    return render_template('index.html', string=string)
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="white-space: pre-line;">{{ string }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show how have you done it? For me it does not work. The string is just one block of text even without new lines.